# How to connect 2nd monitor to iMac 2020 without usb-c?

Tags: display, imac, usb, bluetooth

My iMac 2020 reboots when 2nd monitor is connected via USB-c. I've been through apple support so many times! I gave my iMac to Apple Genius etc. Nobody at Apple is willing to admit that iMac has a malfunction. I've been struggling with it for over 8 months and I know for a fact that it reboots only when I connect any 2nd monitor! Apple thinks I should go to the monitor's manufacturer or to Adobe (since I use Photoshop). I know that this monitor works great with other computers and it's not the only monitor I tried with my iMac. But only my iMac reboots. So support essentially is useless for me and I have to deal with it by myself.

So I wonder is there any other way I can use a second monitor apart from connecting it via USB-c? Is it possible to use a Bluetooth dongle to my second monitor? Are there any other ways?

Here is one of the crash logs:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff023abfa08): x86 CPU CATERR detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 18P4663
macOS version: 20F71
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Fri May  7 22:04:14 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~8/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 7A04D40F-4E77-350D-B90A-DBD2A19DB08D
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.120.36
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0xe
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x1
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x20002000200
PCIeUp link state: 0x94721614
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x000000001bbb4000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff022bb8000
mach_absolute_time: 0x2cbaf4d2c7c
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x60c31b28 0x0002c451
  Sleep   : 0x60c7a3e2 0x00085b10
  Wake    : 0x60c7a41b 0x000479aa
  Calendar: 0x60c7cbe6 0x000caebf

Panicked task 0xffffffe199ffc630: 2882 pages, 189 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe19a0f2c00, backtrace: 0xffffffe804713700, tid: 365
          lr: 0xfffffff0232b349c  fp: 0xffffffe804713750
          lr: 0xfffffff0232b32f4  fp: 0xffffffe8047137c0
          lr: 0xfffffff0233dedf0  fp: 0xffffffe804713890
          lr: 0xfffffff0238d95fc  fp: 0xffffffe8047138a0
          lr: 0xfffffff0232b3028  fp: 0xffffffe804713c20
          lr: 0xfffffff0232b3028  fp: 0xffffffe804713c80
          lr: 0xfffffff02421b200  fp: 0xffffffe804713ca0
          lr: 0xfffffff023abfa08  fp: 0xffffffe804713cd0
          lr: 0xfffffff023aadd98  fp: 0xffffffe804713d30
          lr: 0xfffffff023aafc94  fp: 0xffffffe804713dc0
          lr: 0xfffffff023aad43c  fp: 0xffffffe804713e50
          lr: 0xfffffff0239b20fc  fp: 0xffffffe804713e80
          lr: 0xfffffff02382e010  fp: 0xffffffe804713ec0
          lr: 0xfffffff02382d890  fp: 0xffffffe804713f00
          lr: 0xfffffff0238e45a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: What display is it. What connections does it have? How is it connected at present?Direct USB-C>USB-C, USB-C to [something] converter??

Comment: I can't see how Photoshop (or Adobe) has anything to do with this problem.

Comment: Does the Mac reboot immediately after plugging in the display? - Have you tried plugging in a different display? (or even a TV?) - Have you tried plugging in other USB-C accessories?

Comment: It's Dell U2421HE, 24 inches (direct USB-c to USB-c), but I used other monitors with the same outcome. I also tried my old Apple Cinema which has only HDMI with different adapters. All monitors work fine with other computers. No, it doesn't reboot immediately, but rather randomly. iMac works great with other USB-c devices and without 2nd monitor. Only when a monitor is connected does it reboot. I don't know why Apple Support think that the apps I am using might be the culprit. It reboots sometimes when I just watch Netflix via Chrome and sometimes when I work in Photoshop.

Comment: Does it give the crash warning? https://images.app.goo.gl/7HLtL4dJw9iME8p7A. I’m suspecting that it may be a software or GPU issue and displaylink (my answer) may fix a gpu issue (like how it allows m1 to connect to more than 2 displays) but will rarely fix software issues. If it’s a kernel panic issue, it is more likely to be a hardware or GPU issue.

Comment: @PavelGuzenko Good to h ave these details. When it randomly crashes after some time, do you get any sort of message on screen? - Can you take a look at Console.app after the crash and see if you have a kernel panic - then you can include that information (i.e. the full text of the kernel panic), and from there we can say something about what can be the cause.

Comment: @anonymous it doesn't give this kind of report, it just goes to a black screen and then reboots. After it's on and logged in again it gives me a report which at Apple Support I think they don't read. They even complain to me that these reports are considered private information and they cannot open/read them. I will try to attach one to the topic. But in a nutshell, yes, it's a kernel panic issue.

Comment: @jksoegaard Console usually shows PenTablet which is the driver for the tablet I use. But it was rebooting before I even bought a tablet, so it's definitely not because of the tablet. It might be because of USB-c ports though.

Comment: Was that the whole panic report you included, or only part of it? (if only part of it, then include the whole thing). Regarding your tablet - you should definitely unplug it and plugin the monitor and see if your system stills reboots spontaneously.

Comment: For future reference - pasting large chunks of "code" like this. After you paste, then select it all & hit Ctrl/K [not cmd, ctrl] This will format it legibly. It's had too much manual fiddling to fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about why your monitor is giving issues, but I know that a displaylink usb-a to hdmi or DP adapter, something like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Multi-Display-Converter-Desktop-Projector/dp/B089KM3P5T/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089KM3P5T)

The one-star reviews seem to revolve around the fact that the driver is hard-to-find. It MOST LIKELY (99%) uses displaylink, and in fact (off-topic), allows m1 macs to have more than 2 displays. Use the generic displaylink driver from https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos and you should be good to go.

Comment: It says it doesn't support Mac OS

Comment: I was referring to a type of adapter, not that specific brand. Let me find a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the monitor it's difficult (for me at least) to offer a resolution.  I believe you need to do some more investigation into the cause and see what can be done to avoid the cause.

I have not seen a display with only a USB-C input except portable displays that use DisplayLink or some other USB GPU.  If the display has a USB GPU then look to a driver issue as the cause of the crash.

If you have some other port on the display to connect to the computer then try that.  It is possible there is some hardware issue in the display, cable, or computer that is causing this crash and if you workaround this issue you can keep using the display without crashing.  As an example if your display has a DisplayPort input then find a USB-C to DisplayPort cable to connect the computer to the display.  These cables aren't free, and I suspect you don't want to spend a lot of money on resolving this, but they aren't exactly expensive either.  If a different cable resolves the issue then the problem is solved even if you don't know for sure what the problem was in the first place.

A USB-C to DisplayPort (or whatever port) cable would break many connections between the computer and display, any of which could be the source of your problem.  If all you care about is the video signal to the display then there should be no issue in breaking these non-video connections.  If you do care about these connections then that gets back to doing more investigation to the cause.  A temporary breaking of the non-video connections with an adapter cable will at least prove to you if the source of the problem is in the video signal or some other signal the USB-C cable carries.

I don't know if I've been helpful, I only hope I was helpful.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So Your iMac has Thunderbolt Ports (type C) and I'm assuming your Monitor has a USB Type-C input.

**Option 1** -
If your monitor has other input types such as HDMI, DisplayPort (DP), DVI or VGA then you need to get an Adapter from ThunderBolt/USB-C to HDMI/DP/DVI/VGA. You pretty much have a wide variety of options when it comes to this, just search Thunderbolt Dock on amazon and you will find what you need.

**Option 2** - Airplay. You can use an old computer or Raspberry Pi to act as an airplay server. I use an app called UxPlay on an old computer running Linux then I can wirelessly connect my MacBook to the screen.

**Option 3** - Maybe it's a software bug, have you tried doing a clean install of MacOS? Have you tried using Bootcamp to install Windows and see if the issues persists on Windows?

However I would recommend you send it back for replacement if Option 1 doesn't work because it means your iMac is faulty. When you do take it back ask them to try and connect an external display and see what happens.

NB!!! Make sure you test option one with other Monitors as well before you send it back because it might just be an issue with that particular monitor.